# Android App Development Bluetooth SPP rfcomm

Tags: android, bluetooth, arduino

I'm trying to create an Android App which would allow my Galaxy SIII to connect to my Arduino Board through Bluetooth using a eBay cheap module I just bought.
Thing is, I can't figure out how to make a proper connection and such.

I looked lots of things over the internet, found dozens of source codes, but I still don't understand how it works (I might be dumb, at least a little bit). Some of the source codes I found are very complicated with lots of possibility, and I'm still in the learning process. 
Obviously I tried the http://developer.android.com/ but didn't understand it all.

My question is : Would it be possible to describe me what is required (step by step) to make a connection using an Insecure Rfcomm (I read that online, I might be wrong).
For example : First you need to activate Bluetooth and enable the discovery, then to create a socket ... stuff like that.
I'm obviously willing to have more information than what is written above. (Dunno if willing is very polite, English isn't, as you might have seen, my mother tongue).

For now, I managed to activate bluetooth when checking a checkbox, or if the bluetooth is already enabled, my app check automatically the checkbox. Well what I did is pretty basic, still it works.

My project is basically to send a letter or some letters to my Arduino so that it can interpret it and switch on and off a LED (pretty simple).
And since I'm curious and eager to learn, I want to develop my own app instead of using an already existing one.

In advance, thanks for your time, and thanks for reading my whole message :)
Have a good day !

PS : My code goes like that : http://pastebin.com/k9sSGTuC